# Apache POI Fails to apply table style

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am creating a Table with POI and trying to apply a style to it. but nothing works and the style is not added.

I am following this tutorial: [tutorial](http://thinktibits.blogspot.co.il/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html)

here is the code that defines the style:

> ```
>   CTTableStyleInfo table_style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
>     table_style.setName("TableStyleLight1");
>     table_style.setShowColumnStripes(false); 
>     table_style.setShowRowStripes(true);
> ```

I tryed the styles "TableStyleLight1", "TableStyleLight2", "TableStyleLight3"... etc nothing works, i try to change the name... "Table Style Light 1" which doesn't work as well.

Any ideas how to make this work? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may have resolved this by now but try using. "TableStyleMedium9" I am new to POI at the moment but from my understanding this is a per-defined style in excel so this should work ... as to how to create your own table styles in POI I haven't explored myself yet ... if I find out how I will post back

Answer (score -2):

Just copy whole example with excel generation and try it. It works for me. Extra things don't works